# Develop an Android App over a Flask API

Tags: android, api, flask

I have a website, [Dabble Point](http://www.dabblepoint.com) and it has an API developed in Flask which uses `flask-oauthlib` for authentication and then has standard API for fetching data from database in JSON format. 
I wish to create an Android app over this API, so how can I do it?
Is there a way to fetch and render JSON data as well as to post it? 
Is there any possibility of developing the app other than in java language?

Can **ionic** help help me in developing the android app over the API?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** of course. Get JSON or post it is really easy. You will need to manipulate the JSON. It will be something like that :

To get :

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(yourJsonObject);
JSONObject subObj = jObj.getJSONObject("myJsonNode");
String example = subObj.getString("key");
```